# How to check whether a string was already entered?

Tags: c#, winforms

there is a textbox and by entering the name in it, it checks if there is such a name in the dictionary
if there is, it displays a message and asks to rewrite the name
but I have a keypress that skips all Russian letters and after the output of the name correspondence message the game continues
Here is the code with keypress and button with a check if there is such a name or not:
**The question is how to get around keypress with a duplicate name?**

```
private void Button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var dict = new Dictionary<string, int>(); // where will the data be imported from the file
        using (var stream = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\HP\Desktop\photo\results.txt")) // open file
        {
            // auxiliary elements
            var line = "";
            string[] param;
            // go through all the lines
            while ((line = stream.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                param = line.Split(' '); // Break line
                dict.Add(param[0], Convert.ToInt32(param[1])); // add to dictionary
            }


        }

        if (dict.ContainsKey(textBox1.Text) == false)
        {

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("This name already exists!");
        }
    }

private void TextBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {

        string Symbol = e.KeyChar.ToString();
        if (!Regex.Match(Symbol, @"[а-яА-Я]").Success && (Symbol != "\b"))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }


    }
```

Comment: Have you tried using HashTable instead of a dictionary?

Comment: no, I used the dictionary

Comment: What does the code do now? What do you want it to do instead?

Comment: The code now checks for entering a name in a textbox if there is such a name in the dictionary (I take the names from the dictionary from the file that saves the last entered names). I wrote and if there is such a name, it issues a message box, but the game continues, and it should somehow with a duplicate name re-request the name

Comment: i need to bypass keypress with duplicate name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I suggest *extracting methods*, i.e.

```
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

...

private static Dictionary<string, int> AllNames() {
  return File
    .ReadLines(@"C:\Users\HP\Desktop\картинки\results.txt")
    .Where(line => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
    .Select(item => item.Split(' ')) 
    .ToDictionary(items => items[0], 
                  items => int.Parse(items[1]));
}

private static bool NameExists(string name) {
  return AllNames().ContainsKey(name);
}

private static bool IsValidNameCharacter(char value) {
  // Russian letters are valid ones
  if (value >= 'А' && value <= 'Я' || 
      value >= 'а' && value <= 'я' || 
      value == 'ё' ||
      value == 'Ё')
    return true;

  // ...All the others are not 
  return false;
}
```

Then in order to prevent adding Russian Letters into names, let's test `textBox1.Text` at `TextChanged`:

```
private void Button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if (NameExists(textBox1.Text)) {
    // Let us be nice: put keyboard focus on the problem field
    if (textBox1.CanFocus) {
      textBox1.Focus();
      // textBox1.SelectAll(); // if you want to select all the text
    }

    MessageBox.Show("This name already exists!");

    return; 
  }

  //given name passed validation control (name is all russian letters and unique)
  //TODO: put relevant code here (start the game?)
}

private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  textBox1.Text = string.Concat(textBox1.Text.Where(c => IsValidNameCharacter(c)));
}
```

Comment: I, on the contrary, needed the input to be ONLY Russian characters

Comment: and why, for example, I entered the name Jane and went through the game and at the second entry into the game I enter the same name and can play further?

Comment: redo please! The main tasks of this code are:
1. Enter only Russian letters!
2.If the player has entered a name that is in the dictionary, then issue a messagebox, after which he had to enter the name again (only another)

Comment: @Lines: well, if we accept russian letters only, let's update `IsValidNameCharacter` method.. If user should retype the name, let's give him/her a hint: put keyboard focus on the problem control (`textBox1`)

Comment: why did you delete the solution?

Comment: @Lines: I have no idea how to answer questions like "in what part of the code to write it". Please, extract methods: put, say, a button for adding a new user provide necessary info (what should we do in case of tie, where to get name and score, shall we remove 5th user unconditionally or shall we get top 5 users from initial ones and new one), show your attempt (the button with your implmentation). Please, provide examples of the initial dictionary (file) and the desired outcome.

Comment: So I think the code would be suitable, but I did not understand where to shove it

Comment: help with this please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56395811/how-to-make-the-result-displayed-in-minutes

Comment: @Lines: It's only you who knows it: we have no info. Probably, there's a button `Add New User` or something and when you click it a new user (with name given in some field and score in some other field - where they are we have no info as well) should be written into a file. Here is the natural place to put my deleted code.

Comment: and it had to be added to the code that writes all the information to the file?

Comment: please help with this question !! I beg you! I will choose your answer as the best (I have already chosen the best answer for 2 of your answers) here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56393824/how-to-make-the-removal-of-the-player-s-result-if-he-took-off-from-the-rating

Comment: Your answer was the best, but I just did not understand where to insert this code (I will understand it myself), I promise