# How to make the removal of the player’s result if he “took off” from the rating?

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to make the player removed from the dictionary and from the file if he "flies" out of the rating (ie, takes the 6th place)
I have an idea to do it through Dictionary.Remove and then overwrite it in a file.

I made an algorithm of actions:
Read the file, delete the line in memory, and return the contents to the file (overwrite). If the file is large, you can read its line for the line and create a temporary file, replacing the original file later.

Here is the code for sorting them into places, maybe something will help:

```
private static Dictionary<string, int> AllNames()
    {
        return File
          .ReadLines(@"C:\Users\HP\Desktop\картинки\results.txt")
          .Where(line => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
          .Select(item => item.Split(' '))
          .ToDictionary(items => items[0],
                        items => int.Parse(items[1]));
    }


    private void updateRatingLabels()
    {
        var tops = AllNames()
          .OrderBy(pair => pair.Value)                      
          .ThenBy(pair => pair.Key, StringComparer.Ordinal) 
          .Take(5)                                           
          .ToArray();


        for (int i = 18; i <= 22; ++i)
            Controls.Find($"label{i}", true).First().Text = "";

        for (int i = 28; i <= 32; ++i)
            Controls.Find($"label{i}", true).First().Text = "";


        for (int i = 0; i < tops.Length; ++i)
        {
            Controls.Find($"label{i + 18}", true).First().Text = tops[i].Key;
            Controls.Find($"label{i + 28}", true).First().Text = $"{tops[i].Value / 60}:{tops[i].Value % 60:00}";
        }
    }
```

Comment: What issue are you facing?

Comment: if, for example, the 5th place went lower by rating (6th place), then it should be deleted both from the file and from the dictionary

Comment: but how to do it I have no idea

Comment: what kind of data are present in **AllNames()**?

Comment: Possibly include a screenshot?

Comment: key- player name, value-time in seconds for which the player passed

Comment: I would take a screenshot of the game, but everything is in Russian and you will not understand anything) or are you talking about a screenshot of this part of the code?

Comment: In this case your code seems fine to me. Debug the value of tops. If there is still issue, put screen shots of AllNames() and tops value.

Comment: you didn't understand this code with sorting all the results
and I need if, for example, the 5th place has gone down below the rating (6th place), then it should be removed from both the file and the dictionary

Comment: Below code is Redundant, as you are overwriting values in for loop.

`for (int i = 18; i <= 22; ++i)
 Controls.Find($"label{i}", true).First().Text = "";

for (int i = 28; i <= 32; ++i)
 Controls.Find($"label{i}", true).First().Text = "";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's put the question in a *different way*: we are going *keep* (not *remove*) at most `5` top players. We have to consider what we should do in case of *tie* (i.e. `2` or more players have the *same score*). I think it'll be honest to keep *all* such players (so that the actual dictionary can be *longer* than `5` records):

```
var newDictionary = AllNames()
  .GroupBy(pair => pair.Value)  // groups by scores                    
  .OrderBy(chunk => chunk.Key)  // less seconds the better
  .Take(5)                      // at most 5 groups (ties preserved)                     
  .SelectMany(chunk => chunk)   // flatten back ("ungroup")
  .ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, 
                pair => pair.Value);
```

To save the data into the file, try `File.WriteAllLines`; let's use `"Name Value"` format

```
 File.WriteAllLines(@"c:\TopPlayers.txt", newDictionary
   .Select(pair => $"{pair.Key} {pair.Value}"));
```

**Edit:** If we have to add an user, with `name` and `score` we can do it in `2` ways:

Whatever `score` is remove `5`th place and add new user:

```
 var newDictionary = AllNames()
  .GroupBy(pair => pair.Value)  // groups by scores                    
  .OrderBy(chunk => chunk.Key)  // less seconds the better
  .Take(4)                      // at most 4 groups (ties preserved)                     
  .SelectMany(chunk => chunk)   // flatten back ("ungroup")
  .ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, 
                pair => pair.Value);

 newDictionary.Add(name, score);
```

Add new user, then take top `5` (note, that new user can be excluded as a lower performer)

```
 var newDictionary = AllNames()
  .Concat(new KeyValuePair<string, int>[] { 
     new KeyValuePair<string, int>(name, score)} // All new users here
   )
  .GroupBy(pair => pair.Value)  // groups by scores                    
  .OrderBy(chunk => chunk.Key)  // less seconds the better
  .Take(5)                      // at most 5 groups (ties preserved)                     
  .SelectMany(chunk => chunk)   // flatten back ("ungroup")
  .ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, 
                pair => pair.Value);
```

**Edit 2:** So you can implement a method like

```
 private void SaveNewUser(string name, int score) {
   var newDictionary = AllNames()
     .GroupBy(pair => pair.Value)     // groups by scores                    
     .OrderBy(chunk => chunk.Key)     // less seconds the better
     .Take(4)                         // at most 4 groups (ties preserved)         
     .SelectMany(chunk => chunk)      // flatten back ("ungroup")
     .ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, 
                  pair => pair.Value);

   newDictionary.Add(name, score);

   File.WriteAllLines(@"c:\TopPlayers.txt", newDictionary
     .Select(pair => $"{pair.Key} {pair.Value}"));
 }
```

which you can call somewhere on, say, a button click:

```
 private void saveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   SaveNewUser(textBoxWithName.Text, int.Parse(textBoxWithScore.Text));
 }
```

Comment: @Lines: suppose you have palyers `"A 1", "B 1", "C 1", "D 2", "E 2", "F 2", "G 3"`. I suggest it would be honest to keep `"A 1", "B 1", "C 1", "D 2", "E 2", "F 2"` - **6** of them without excluding `"F 2"`

Comment: probably you did not understand the essence of the task
I need:
1. To make it so that with a new record player he was added to the rating, and the last player who was in 5th place, he leaves the rating, that is. his record is no longer shown. And you need to delete this player.

Comment: @Lines: well, you should put the code to the routine which is responsible to adding a new user.

Comment: @Lines: `private void updateRatingLabels2() {var newDictionary = ...; File.WriteAllLines(...);}`

Comment: excuse me, I apparently poorly formulated a goal. It is to the point that there is some kind of dictionary, the elements of which are taken from a file, and are written to a file based on the entered data from another form.
The goal is:
Here are all 5 places filled (that is, all 5 places are distributed between players), I play 6 game and beat someone's

Comment: record (let's say 4 place surpassed) 4 place goes down to 5th place, and 5th place is no longer shown (it leaves the rating ) so this 5 place should be removed from the dictionary

Comment: from this dictionary private static Dictionary<string, int> AllNames()
        {
            return File
              .ReadLines(@"C:\Users\HP\Desktop\картинки\results.txt")
              .Where(line => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
              .Select(item => item.Split(' '))
              .ToDictionary(items => items[0],
                            items => int.Parse(items[1]));
        }

Comment: I will change the conditions of the question (I will make it easier), you do not need to delete the entire line from the file but then update the entire file again only without the player who left the rating!