# How to make the result displayed in minutes?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a code that takes the data from the dictionary and writes it into a label, but in which they are. And I need to do so that it is recorded in the format of minutes, that is:

minutes: seconds

mm: ss

Here is the code that performs the mapping to the label:

```
private void updateRatingLabels2()
    {
        var tops = AllNames2()
          .OrderBy(pair => pair.Value) 
          .ThenBy(pair => pair.Key, StringComparer.Ordinal) 
          .Take(5)   
          .ToArray();


        for (int i = 23; i <= 27; ++i)
            Controls.Find($"label{i}", true).First().Text = "";

        for (int i = 33; i <= 37; ++i)
            Controls.Find($"label{i}", true).First().Text = "";


        for (int i = 0; i < tops.Length; ++i)
        {
            Controls.Find($"label{i + 23}", true).First().Text = tops[i].Key;
            Controls.Find($"label{i + 33}", true).First().Text = tops[i].Value.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Consider TimeSpan.ToString(...) to get location-aware formatting.  Initialize perhaps with TimeSpan.FromSeconds(), it isn't obvious what "Value" represents.

Comment: `Controls.Find($"label{i + 33}", true).First().Text = $"{tops[i].Value / 60} : {tops[i].Value % 60:00}";` if `tops[i].Value` contains seconds (e.g. `1204` and we want `20 : 04`)

Comment: value-This is the number of seconds for which the player passed the game

Comment: Sorry, code that uses default names and Controls.Find()? You might want to at least cache the controls in a global array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the value within the dictionary is a string of datetime you could try using DateTime.Parse like this:

```
var val = tops[i].Value.ToString();
 Controls.Find($"label{i + 33}", true).First().Text = DateTime.Parse(val).ToString("mm:ss") ;
```